# user permissions

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

im doing project for a school...and new to php and mysql..just learning..

i have to create one loginpage with 3 different users like corres,principal and the staff

in the table field what type i have to give like ENUM or SET..
i want to assign 0 for corr,1 for princi and 3 for staff..

how to do this and shud i give any field in the login page in php??

but im going to create only 2 tables one for corr and other one is for staff

corr table fields r corrs_id,username,password,staff_id,staff_role

staff table fields r staff_id,staff_role,name,qualification,address,state etc...

both the tables have 2 common fields staff_id and staff_role
now how to connect 2 tables and when username and password is given it shud first check the staff_role like 'princ' or a 'staff'

please help me....

Comment: Oh come on, if you are crossposting stuff using copy&paste at least remove the unrelated things you accidentally copied...

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't keep two same fields in 2 tables if you can get rid of one. Read about database normalization first.
2. Remove the staff_role field from the corr table and leave only the staff_id to join both tables as I said above.
3. The two tables are joinable using this exact staff_id

---

```
select u.name,r.role from users u
inner join roles r
on u.role_id=r.id
where r.role='princ' and u.username='bleh' and u.password='bleh'
```

Cheers

Comment: ok how to join 3 tables with one common field..like table1:c_id,username password,c_role assigned as 1 and table2:p_id,username,password,c_role assigned as 2 and table:s_id,username,password,c_role and common field is c_role assigned as 3

Comment: This sounds like a wrong architecture.3 tables with 3 same fields? You would need only like 2 tables in this case like USERS table and ROLES table and thats about it. The role_id will be in the USERS table referencing the primary key ID in the ROLES table and that's about it. To join them use a simple join as I wrote in the example.